# Make a standard deviation always positive in Metropolis-Hastings

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, statistics

I am trying Bayesian regression using Metropolis-Hastings. The test data is generated as follows (Python code, I didn't copy the entire code):

```
trueA = 5 ; trueB = 7 ;trueSD = 10 ; sample_size = 261
x = np.arange(-sample_size/8, sample_size/8, (sample_size*2/8)/sample_size)
y = trueA *x + trueB + npr.normal(loc=0, scale=trueSD, size=sample_size)
```

I defined log likelihood as follows:

```
def likelihood(param):
    a = param[0][0] ; b = param[0][1] ; sd = param[0][2] ; pred = a*x + b
    sumSqError = np.power((y - pred), 2).sum()
    likelihoodsum = ((sample_size/2)*(np.log(1)-np.log(np.power(sd,2)))) + (- 1/(2*np.power(sd,2)) * sumSqError)
    return likelihoodsum
```

To make next points, I prepared the following function:

```
def next_param(param, param_index):
    a_next = param[0][0] ; b_next = param[0][1] ; sd_next = param[0][2]

    if param_index == 0:
        a_next = param[0][0] + npr.normal(0, 0.1)
    elif param_index == 1:
        b_next = param[0][1] + npr.normal(0, 0.1)
    elif param_index == 2:
        sd_next = param[0][2] + npr.normal(0, 0.1)

    return np.array([[a_next, b_next, sd_next]])
```

This code works well (acceptance rate is high enough and I can estimate the parameters), though I know `sd_next` can go negative in the above code, which is weird.

So, I decided to use log for `sd_next`:

```
elif param_index == 2:
  sd_next = np.log(param[0][2]) + npr.normal(0, 0.1)

return np.array([[a_next, b_next, np.exp(sd_next)]])
```

However, the estimated parameters are far from the true values. How can I make a standard deviation always positive in Metropolis-Hastings?

JFI, here is MCMC part:

```
num_sampling = 1000
chain = np.zeros((num_sampling, 1, 3))
chain[0][0][0] = 20 # starting value for a
chain[0][0][1] = 15 # starting value for b
chain[0][0][2] = 15 # starting value for sd

num_accepted = 0
for i in range(num_sampling-1):
    chain_previous = chain[i][:]
    chain_new = np.zeros((1, 1, 3))

    for p in range(3):
        proposal = next_param(chain_previous, p)

        probab = likelihood(proposal) - likelihood(chain_previous)
        if 0 < probab:
            chain_new[0][0][p] = proposal[0][p]
            num_accepted += 1
        else:
            chain_new[0][0][p] = chain[i][0][p]

    chain[i+1] = chain_new[0][:]
```

Comment: There are several ways. A simple trick is to switch to log sigma (but beware that it will require to consider the Jacobian of the transformation, like any change of coordinates of probability densities).

Comment: @lacerbi Thanks. Do you know any good references for calculating "log sigma"?

Comment: It is a standard transform. See e.g. the Stan user manual (this is Stan paper: http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/stan_jebs_2.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

It is not weird at all that you get a negative standard deviation $\sigma$ when your proposal is a Normal distribution, with support $(-\infty,+\infty)$.

And the Metropolis-Hastings accept-reject step should also include the prior distribution on the three parameters. Including the Jacobian when the proposal is on $\log\sigma$.

**As written the Metropolis-Hastings accept-reject step is incorrect!**

```
if 0 < probab:
```

is not the right condition for accepting a move to the proposed value: one should compared the (log-)probability with a (log-)uniform. In the current format, you converge to a maximum of the likelihood.

Comment: Thanks. I understand my code might return negative SD since I used a Normal distribution. However, the entire code gives good estimates of parameters, so I wonder it is fine to return negative SD (although it is theoretically wrong) in the MH process. / I suppose uniform distributions as an uninformative prior. That's why I only calculated likelihood.

Comment: I added MCMC part in the original question.

Comment: Do you mean I need to change to `np.exp(0) < probab`?

Comment: I do not understand this code but the way `probab` is written it should rather be `log(runif(1))` [in R] or something similar in python.

Comment: I mean something like `if log(npr.unif(0,1)) < probab` (and you should make the effort to read a textbook about Metropolis-Hastings as you definitely lack the basics).

Comment: Thanks again. Actually, I referred to MacKay's textbook. On page 366, it says we need to check $P^*(X') / P(x^{(t)}) \geq 1$ (I skipped $Q$ since I used symmetric distribution). And I thought $\log P^*(X') - \log P(x^{(t)}) \geq \log1 = 0$. Why do I have to draw a value from uniform distriburion?

Comment: Read the entire chapter. And another book if this is not clear enough.